# Can we conclude that the mandate to keep a literal seventh day Sabbath is obsolete from Exodus 31:12-17, Hebrews 8 and Hebrews 4?

Tags: exodus, hebrews, covenant, sabbath, ten-commandments

I will present 3 passages from Scripture and what I understand from each one.

1) Exodus 31:12-17 (NIV)

> 12 Then the Lord said to Moses, 13 “Say to the **Israelites**, ‘You must observe my Sabbaths. This will be **a sign between me and you for the generations to come**, so you may know that I am the Lord, who makes you holy. 14 “‘Observe the Sabbath, **because it is holy to you**. Anyone who desecrates it is to be put to death; those who do any work on that day must be cut off from their people. 15 For six days work is to be done, but the seventh day is a day of sabbath rest, holy to the Lord. Whoever does any work on the Sabbath day is to be put to death. 16 The **Israelites** are to observe the Sabbath, celebrating it for the generations to come as a **lasting covenant**. 17 It will be a **sign between me and the Israelites forever**, for in six days the Lord made the heavens and the earth, and on the seventh day he rested and was refreshed.’”

From this passage I understand that the commandment to keep a seventh day Sabbath is a covenant sign between God and the Israelites. God established a covenant between Him and the Israelites, and the Sabbath is a sign of that covenant.

2) Hebrews 8:6-13 (NIV)

> 6 But in fact the ministry Jesus has received is as superior to theirs **as the covenant of which he is mediator is superior to the old one, since the new covenant is established on better promises**. 
> 7 **For if there had been nothing wrong with that first covenant, no place would have been sought for another**. 8 But God found fault with the people and said:
> “The days are coming, declares the Lord,when I will make **a new covenant** with the people of Israel and with the people of Judah. 9 It will not be like the covenant I made with their ancestors when I took them by the hand to lead them out of Egypt, because they did not remain faithful to my covenant, and I turned away from them, declares the Lord. 10 This is the covenant I will establish with the people of Israel after that time, declares the Lord. I will put my laws in their minds and write them on their hearts. I will be their God, and they will be my people. 11 No longer will they teach their neighbor, or say to one another, ‘Know the Lord,’ because they will all know me, from the least of them to the greatest. 12 For I will forgive their wickedness and will remember their sins no more.”
> 13 By calling this covenant “new,” **he has made the first one obsolete; and what is obsolete and outdated will soon disappear.**

From this passage I understand that, due to Israel's disobedience, the old covenant has become obsolete and has been replaced by a new covenant with Jesus as its mediator.

3) Hebrews 4:1-11 (NIV)

> Therefore, since **the promise of entering his rest still stands**, let us be careful that none of you be found to have fallen short of it. 2 For we also have had the good news proclaimed to us, just as they did; but the message they heard was of no value to them, because they did not share the faith of those who obeyed. 3 **Now we who have believed enter that rest**, just as God has said, 
> “So I declared on oath in my anger, ‘They shall never enter my rest.’”
> And yet his works have been finished since the creation of the world. 4 For somewhere he has spoken about the seventh day in these words: “On the seventh day God rested from all his works.” 5 And again in the passage above he says, “They shall never enter my rest.”
> 6 Therefore **since it still remains for some to enter that rest**, and since **those who formerly had the good news proclaimed to them did not go in because of their disobedience**, 7 **God again set a certain day, calling it “Today.”** This he did when a long time later he spoke through David, as in the passage already quoted:
> “**Today**, if you hear his voice, do not harden your hearts.”
> 8 For if Joshua had given them rest, God would not have spoken later about **another day**. 9 **There remains, then, a Sabbath-rest for the people of God**; 10 for anyone who enters God’s rest also rests from their works, just as God did from his. 11 Let us, therefore, make every effort to enter that rest, so that no one will perish by following their example of disobedience.

From this passage I understand that the Israelites, due to their disobedience, were not able to enter God's rest. However, those who believe (Christians) can enter that Sabbath-rest, no longer each seventh day, but today (a sort of "present moment" rest).

In short, from these 3 passages I conclude that:

1. The mandate to keep a seventh day Sabbath was given to the Israelites as a sign of the old covenant.
2. The old covenant is obsolete and has been replaced with a new covenant mediated by Jesus.
3. Christians in the new covenant can enter a Sabbath-rest in the present moment ("today").
4. Therefore, the commandment to keep a literal physical rest every seventh day is obsolete.

Are my conclusions accurate?

Comment: This is off-topic for two reasons. 1) It is not an enquiry about a particular verse or word ; it is about a topic. 2) It is not a genuine question, it is an attempt to express a view and merely seeks an approbation.

Comment: @NigelJ: this question has a similar structure to a [previous one](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/50937/are-christians-being-licensed-not-to-keep-the-sabbath-according-to-colossians-2) I asked, and the moderators never closed it as off-topic, so I assumed this question would be on-topic too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about systematic theology, not Biblical exposition.

Comment: I have no issue with the text, the way you interpret the text or the conclusion you draw. So yes. Further, there is nothing I can think of that opposes this conclusion.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica I see. Any edits then to the question you would recommend to salvage it from closure?

Comment: There are numerous people on both sides of this theological divide on this site.  However, this is not a site for systematic theology but Bible hermeneutics.  All I suggest is this, in the "New Covenant" what is the associated "law" that required of the recipient of the blessings and promises?